How to add FormArray to FormGroup without declaring , and adding programmatically
I trying to learn to create generic template for form where in passing json, would define the
structure for the table rendered.
I am unable to add controls and form array to the fromGroup programmatically without declaring it earlier
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ksvegt?file=src%2Fmain.ts
here is the code, please help me with this issue, and is it the right approach to do it

NOT use setControl else addControl
  createForm(jsonData: JsonForm) {
    this.form1.addControl('header', new FormControl(jsonData.header));
    const controlArray = this.fb.array([]);
    for (let control of jsonData.controls || []) {
      controlArray.push(this.fb.control(control.value));
    }
    this.form1.addControl('controls', controlArray);
  }

Always you have a fromArray use a getter to "reach" it and iterate over it
  get controls()
  {
    return this.form1.get('controls') as any as FormArray
  }

And you use
  <form [formGroup]="form1">
    <div
      formArrayName="controls"
      *ngFor="let control of controls.controls; let i = index"
    >
      <input  [formControlName]="i" />
    </div>
  </form>

Your forked stackblitz
Well, this solve your code, but I feel that the way to create a formGroup is really create a formGroup, not a formArray
In this way the value of your formGroup have the structure of your json data
For this, I add a new property to your JsonFormControls interface, name, that it's the name of the property
  createForm(jsonData: JsonForm) {

    //to iterate over an array use forEach instead a for
    (jsonData.controls || []).forEach((control:JsonFormControls,index:number)=>{
      this.form1.addControl(control.name ||'ctrl'+index,
                            new FormControl(control.value))
    })
  }

Well, now "how iterate"?
It's not a good idea iterate over jsonData.controls else you can iterate over form.controls using keyvaluePipe
<ng-template #DEFAULT_FORM_TITILE let-form="form1">
  <h2>{{ jsonData.header }}</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="form1">

   <!-see you iterate over form1.controls|keyvalue
      you use let i=index, to get the value of the jsonData.controls[i]
      -->
    <div *ngFor="let control of form1.controls|keyvalue;let i=index">

     <!--sorry the "!", it's to avoid errors of "object can be undefined"-->
     <label>{{jsonData!.controls![i].label}}

      <input [type]="jsonData!.controls![i]?.type || null" 
             [formControlName]="jsonData!.controls![i]?.name || null" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!--just for check-->
  <pre>
  {{form1.value|json}}
  </pre>
</ng-template>

A new stackblitz
